# I need to create a Tasker profile with a scene that blocks the incomming popup

Tags: overlay, scene, tasker

I used to play mobile games and stream them online. While I'm streaming if someone calls me their contact name and mobile number is visible to the viewers. I don't want that to happen. So, searched internet a lot never find an app that works the way I wanted. Finally decided to create a Tasker profile with a scene task. But that ain't works either. I mean it works but it won't overlay over the incoming popup. How make the scene overlay over the incoming system popup???

If you've any other solution for my need that would be appreciated. I just want to hide caller name and mobile number. Thank you....

I will provide the screenshot below....

This is the tasker profile I've created

[Tasker Overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdOOh.jpg)

This is the result when I receiving incoming call the tasker scene fall behind the incoming popup..

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvjlL.jpg)

Comment: The link to Tasker overlay is showing the wrong picture, please share your tasker profile so we can help you.
You can set taker to auto reject/accept the call (if rooted) so it won't show any number on the screen while the game is open by automatically rejecting or accepting calls.

Comment: what is your android version @Adirai Maji

Comment: I don't meant to show the tasker profile in Tasker Overlay link. I just showing the overlay design without incoming call....

And the second Picture is with incoming call..

I'm on Android 7 Nougat,{ MIUI v9 (Redmi Note 4)}

And I don;t wanna auto reject/Accept the calls either. (I'm root user)

Comment: Since it's android 7 why don't you simply use Android's built-in "do not disturb"?

Comment: @Tomaski Will I get Incoming call in background If I enable DND??? Or The incoming call gets rejected automatically?

Comment: it depends on how you set it up, but the short answer is "no" - ALL notifications are to be suppressed when DND is active. The call is not rejected: you DO see an incoming call icon on the statusbar (so that you know that SOMEONE is calling you and can expand the notification area to see who that is and take it), but thats about it - no popup-like notifications will be (should be) shown.

Comment: @Tomaski I've tested DND. It doesn't hide the incoming pop-up notification.

Comment: well, my experience is, that MIUI developers like to "tweak" some things to their likings, so some features might (and very often do) work differently. Did you go through the DND settings and tweaked it to your needs (i.e. exceptions list)? Or simply activated it by clicking it's tile? AFAIK default exception for MIUI is `all contacts`